# How can $\exists x \in X P(x) \rightarrow ((P(c) \rightarrow Q) → Q)$ be true?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

$x$ is a natural number

$X$ is a set of all natural numbers

$P$ is a one-place predicate

For context, this statement is found [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification#Rules_of_Inference) If the proposition of a material conditional can be true while both of the propositions it joins are false (i.e $P \rightarrow Q$ is true if both $P$ and $Q$ are false) then how can the proposition in the title be true?

If we deduct the proposition $P(c) \rightarrow Q$ and assume both $P(c)$ and $Q$ are false, the proposition would still be true. And if we assume both $P(c)$ and $Q$ are false then how can $((P(c) \rightarrow Q) \rightarrow Q)$ be valid at all? If $Q$ is false and $P(c) \rightarrow Q$ is true then the proposition $((P(c) \rightarrow Q) → Q)$ is self-contradictory.

What am I missing here?

The only thing I can think of is that the proposition in the title implies that the predicate, $P(c)$, is true if the proposition $\exists x \in X P(x)$ is true because $P(c)$ is just a different representation of $P(x)$. But I cannot confirm this and the phrasing in that paragraph is vague to me.

Also, as a side question, have I used terminology appropriately here?

Comment: Please use MathJax when writing mathematics. Also, $P$ is not a function but a one-place predicate.

Comment: In the context I have linked, it is stated P() is a propositional function. "For example, if P(x) is the propositional function"

Comment: But that is precisely what a predicate is.

Comment: Is it a "statement" or a "proposition" in the title? These words seem to be used interchangeably

Comment: As per @Hagen's answer, you have to reason intuitively at the semantical level. We have two premises: $(\exists x \in X) P(x), P(c) \to Q$, plus other unspecified assumptions. Whatever is the domain you use to interpet the argument, we know that set $X$ is not empty and that the property $P$ is instantiated; thus, we can always choose a reference for constant $c$ such that $P$ holds of it, and this is possible because $c$ is never "used" in $Q, P(x)$ or any other background assumptions (it is new): thus, we have no constraints on it. But if $P(c)$ is true and also $P(c) \to Q$ is, then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia page you cite is wrong. It is a valid inference rule to infer $Q$ from $\exists x.P(x)$ and $P(c) \to Q$, where $c$ is some constant that does not appear in $Q$:
$$
{{{\exists x.P(x)} \quad P(c) \to Q} \over Q} \quad\mbox{[where $c$ does not appear in $Q$]}
$$

However, that does not mean that the implication $\exists x.P(x) \to (P(c) \to Q) \to Q$ is provable.

The rule is valid, because if you can prove $P(c) \to Q$ and $\exists x. P(x)$ then $P(c) \to Q$ holds in any model including the model in which $c$ is interpreted as the  witness to $\exists x. P(x)$ (which exists in every model since $\exists x. P(x)$ is provable), but that means that $Q$ holds in any model, since the truth value of $Q$ does not depend on the value assigned to $c$. The implication  $\exists x.P(x) \to (P(c) \to Q) \to Q$ need not hold in every model. E.g., take $P(x) \equiv \exists y.x = 2y$ (i.e., $P(x)$ says "$x$ is even") and take $Q \equiv 1 = 2$. Then $\exists x.P(x) \to (P(c) \to Q) \to Q$ does not hold if $c$ is interpreted as $1$ (since it reduces to $\mathsf{true}\to\mathsf{true} \to \mathsf{false}$).

A way of seeing this thinking about proofs rather than models is that $c$ in the inference rule can be considered to be universally quantified (because it only appears in the deduction of $P(c) \to Q$ and not in $Q$ itself). So the rule works like:

$$
{{{\exists x.P(x)} \quad  \forall y(P(y) \to Q)} \over Q} \quad\mbox{[where $y$ does not appear in $Q$]}
$$

Comment: Ok I think I get it. So the truth value of the proposition in my title is uncertain because it can't be proven but is nonetheless reasonable to infer? My beef is with the seemingly incoherent relation of ∃x. P(x) to P(c) and Q. Both c and Q seem to be independent from each other and from any other "variable" mentioned in the proposition. That section "Rules of Inference" in the wikipedia article I link, which is where the proposition in question is found, is very confusingly phrased, very hard to interpret

Comment: I've made some updates to my answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: "Then ∃x.P(x)→(P(c)→Q)→Q does not hold if c is interpreted as 1 (since it reduces to true→true→false)." Thank you, that's what I've been trying to say. This proposition breaks in the model where P(c) and Q are both false because the proposition would be reduced to the truth value of true→true→false. Also I see you edited your initial answer to say that the Wikipedia article is just flat out wrong so I'm going to stop harping on this problem. It also seems to me that you are saying the article is assuming P(c) is always true because c is a constant and is universally quantified.

Answer (score 1):

$c$ is an object that we named but that is otherwise explicitly unspecified. Is $P(c)$ true then? Well, maybe, maybe not, we cannot know. There are only two situations where we can conclude that $P(c)$ *must* be true or *must* be false: If $\forall x P(x)$, then necessarily $P(c)$. If $\forall x\neg P(x)$, the necessarily $\neg P(x)$. Here, we are but interested in $\exists xP(x)$. Then it is certainly *possible* that $P(c)$ is true, whereas we have no idea whether $\neg P(c)$ can be true. Now if we can derive $P(c)\to Q$, then $Q$ (which does not depend on $c$) cannot be false, for it *may* (and we are given that it *can*) happen that $P(c)$ is true. As even in that case $P(c)\to Q$ must hold, it must be the case that $Q$ is true.

Comment: +1 for a clear explanation. The only thing I don't like in it is the parentheses around "which does not depend on $c$", because I suspect this point my be the (or at least a) source of the OP's difficulty. I suspect this because I've found that students far too often learn a lot of formulas while ignoring the surrounding prose, like "no $c$ in $Q$". And here, of course, this bit of surrounding prose is crucial for the validity of the inference.

Comment: "Then it is certainly possible that P(c) is true, whereas we have no idea whether ¬P(c) can be true." We have no idea whether either is true, correct? We only know that either could be true? I was not confused about "c not being in Q" I'm confused on the connection between P(x) and P(c). My thought process at the moment is that it's possible for P(x) to be true and P(c) to be false; if P(c) is false then P(c)→Q can still be true as long as Q is false as well; but this scenario would contradict (P(c)→Q)→Q would it not? I had to ask this question now, I'm sorry for not using mathjax I'm learning

Comment: "for it may (and we are given that it can) happen that P(c) is true. As even in that case P(c)→Q must hold." It may also be that P(c) is false, in which case P(c)→Q would still hold if both P(c) and Q are false. I'm sorry, I know I'm missing something big here, and it may just be that this question is out of my league